# Can't reach router admin page

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

So, this weekend I attempted to install DD-WRT on my router (WNR3500Lv2, latest Kong build)... and I'm not sure how it went: I can no longer reach my router admin page.

- 30-30-30 resets don't appear to have any effect.
- router boots, and lights up properly (although might be taking a while).
- wireless light is on, but nothing I have can see the wireless network.
- Wired connections work, sort of: I can potentially ping other machines on the network(might only work if the destination requested a static ip); turning on network discovery *does* result in the computers being visible in Windows.
- Ethernet connection to the modem is detected, but router doesn't go online (modem is outside in box, probably can't powercycle it).  Attempting pass-though from another router doesn't work.
- No default gateway is assigned, and the auto-assigned ip is unusual.  Attempting to manually set the client ip/gateway hasn't helped.

I've about exhausted what I can figure out so far.  Even somehow getting this thing back to the factory firmware would be an improvement.

In case it's needed, `ipconfig /all` generates the following from one machine:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : GREMLIN
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : D-Link DFE-530TX+ PCI Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-11-95-1D-EB-B7
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::419f:7a91:4d76:b9d5%14(Preferred) 
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.185.213(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 301994389
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-66-A5-E1-00-18-F3-76-03-6C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{EDEF02B6-A95E-43F3-9A8A-0D8B1DD05FB3}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: If you want to first-time connect to the newly flashed router you should set your computer's IPv4 address manually. IP should be something like 192.168.1.2 and your gateway should be 255.255.255.0. then you can try access 192.168.1.1 in your browser and see if this works.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work, put that in the question already.

Comment: `169.254.185.213` DHCP is not working ....

Comment: **1.** power off the machines getting the 169.254.x.x addresses and keep them powered off (all wired and wireless devices).
**2.** Now, unplug the power from your router and wait two minutes with the electrical power disconnected and then plug it back in and let it power up.
**3.** Wait five minutes and now start up the machine with the issue.
Check the IP assignment on the device connected to the router now and see if things are back to normal.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I'm aware, thank you.  Manually assigning IPs doesn't let me in either (although machines with assigned IPs can be pinged).

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT - No dice.

Comment: **4.** Your next step is to do a **Restore Factory Settings** by **holding the red button in** on the back of the router--Use the end of a paper clip or some other
similar object to press and hold the **Restore Factory Settings** button on the bottom of the
router for at least 7 seconds. Once this is complete and the router reboots, see if it's functioning properly now and report back your findings please. If you don't notice the device restart or reboot, you may want to pull the power from it again after the factory reset.

Comment: Also, when you say ***"I attempted to install DD-WRT on my router"*** can you confirm if you've: **1**. updated firmware on your router, **2**. you connected this router to an existing network and connected it to another router/modem, **3.** you've connected this router to a new network entirely or you are replacing a different router, and **4.** confirm whether this is a home or business network and whether or not it should be able to connect to the Internet.

Comment: 1) Don't know what the status is, since I can't hit the admin page to check. 2)  Tried to connect it to another router, but it didn't pick up the internet through it.  3) Mostly been trying to connect just to the router, as a new network, not even hooked up to the internet.  4) Home network.  The one time I tried to hook it up to the internet it could see the line, but not dial out (modem probably expects specific router).  5) Resetting _appears_ to have no effect; I still can't talk to the admin page, and I'm not sure it even causes a reboot.

Comment: Maybe you can try just connecting your computer to the router, set up a static IP on your computer eg 192.168.1.119 / 255.255.0.0 (notice the slash 16 network) and scan the 192.168.0.0/16 range so you find out the routers IP after the installation.

Comment: @Zina - Already tried that, it's part of the question.  Nothing in the 1.0/255 range, nothing in the 0.0/8 range

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Based on all your results (assuming you tried a different network cable too), I'd think this is a defective or broken router since everything you try has no success. Try another network cable if you can or already haven't but otherwise if that doesn't work you might consider to reaching out to support with the router or seeing if you have a warranty, or replacing with a new router. I'm not sure if a picture of your setup would be helpful or not but I'm about out of ideas without being there and seeing your equipment, double-testing, etc.

Comment: If you reset the the router and then reboot the PC it's connected to and ensure it's set to get DHCP IP address, the IP address to try in the web address bar once the factory reset is complete should be http://192.168.1.1 so try that if you've not and reboot the PC it's connected to via an Ethernet port. It sounds like you may have updated firmware and had this issue afterwards? Not sure if there is another way to push firmware update to the device other than the Ethernet port but you may want to read about that for the router you have.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT - Tried that, yeah.

Comment: Can't see you tested what you said you did. You mentioned you can discover other Windows computers. Nevertheless, you tried and seems the router has no IP but the switch part is working. The only other thing I can think of is to try to boot from tftp Even if you mentioned the 30-30-30 method, the following link has a 30-30-30-10-10 procedure (and says try at least 10 times). [See instructions for another model here](https://community.netgear.com/t5/General-WiFi-Routers/Guide-How-to-quot-unbrick-quot-your-WGR614v9-after-a-bad/td-p/153385) . Hopefully you will be able to repair it.

Comment: @Zina - alas, that hasn't worked so far, either.  It _does_ look like the router listens on 192.168.1.1 for a short period, but I haven't been able to get a connection across, or the firmware isn't uploading in time, or something.  I may just have to try wiring up a terminal cable inside...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router appears to have actually been stuck in bridge/repeater mode (in that plugging into a different LAN port enabled accessing the internet), but I still wasn't able to access the admin page.

Unfortunately, in my attempts to use a terminal cable to reflash the router, I ended up over-volting the router and fried it.

Comment: "I ended up over-volting the router and fried it." My god, what did that router ever do to you?!! ;-;